# Calculate rolling correlation using rollapply

Tags: r, zoo

I have zoo object with 10000+ rows.

```
> head(tt)
                      A             B
2007-01-04  0.005945924  0.0021167475
2007-01-05 -0.004201991 -0.0080020024
2007-01-08  0.001740897  0.0045804104
2007-01-09  0.000000000 -0.0008163931
2007-01-10 -0.004503531  0.0032615812
2007-01-11 -0.005841138  0.0043863282
```

I have tried variations of the following line, but to no avail.

```
rollapply(tt, 21, function(x) cor(x[,1],x[,2]))
```

Every entry gave correlation of 1, looks like it's picking up the 1 off the diagonal of the correlation matrix.

```
2013-11-25  1  1
2013-11-26  1  1
2013-11-27  1  1
2013-11-29  1  1
2013-12-02  1  1
2013-12-03  1  1
```

What I really want is -0.4649, like the following

```
> cor(tt)
           A          B
A  1.0000000 -0.4649881
B -0.4649881  1.0000000
```

Answer (score 14):

For your simple case, you could use `TTR::runCor`.

```
set.seed(21)
x <- rnorm(30)
y <- rnorm(30)
z <- zoo(cbind(x,y),Sys.Date()-1:30)
tail(rollapplyr(z, 21, function(x) cor(x[,1],x[,2]), by.column=FALSE))
tail(runCor(z[,1],z[,2],21))
```

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this:

```
x<-rnorm(100)
y<-rnorm(100)
rollapply(data.frame(x,y), 21 ,function(x) cor(x[,1],x[,2]), by.column=FALSE)
```

In other words, I think you may just need the `by.column=FALSE` argument.
Works with a zoo object too

```
rollapply(zoo(cbind(x,y),Sys.Date()-1:100), 21 ,function(x) cor(x[,1],x[,2]), by.column=FALSE)
```

#### Edit to address a question from the comment about adding another column.

You can specify the columns you want to use in the `cor` function.

```
z<-rnorm(100)
rollapply(zoo(cbind(x,y,z),Sys.Date()-1:100), 21 ,function(x) cor(x[,1],x[,3]), by.column=FALSE)
rollapply(zoo(cbind(x,y,z),Sys.Date()-1:100), 21 ,function(x) cor(x[,2],x[,3]), by.column=FALSE)
```

`by.column=FALSE` indicates that the function should not be applied to each column separately.  If `by.column=TRUE`, then the function will be applied to each column separately, and this is the default behavior.

Comment: it works! what exactly does the by.column option do?  if i was to have a 3x3 cor matrix, how would one go about picking up the right correlation?

Comment: @Jota, thanks for the comments, I asked the same question about more columns to Joshua Ulrich and then saw your amendments so I just deleted it, apoloiges. If I had 100 columns of data is there a more efficient way to run the cor function rather than specifying each pair? Could this be achieved using one of the apply family functions?

Comment: You can use this function in `rollapply` to handle any number of columns: `function(x) cor(x)[lower.tri(cor(x))]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to compute 6 month running correlations using `tq_transmute_xy` from the `tidyquant` package:

```
library(tidyquant)
    
x<-rnorm(100)
y<-rnorm(100)
    
zoo(cbind(x,y),Sys.Date()-1:100)
    
tq_transmute_xy(x = x, y = y, 
                mutate_fun = runCor,
                n = 6,
                col_rename = "rolling.corr.6")
```

Comment: You need to add explanations to your code for better understanding