# Calculate rolling correlation for all permutations of columns in a DF

Tags: r, correlation, rolling-computation, rollapply

I have a table that contains 4 numeric vectors, I would like to calculate and populate a new table that shows the rolling correlation of each possible column pair.

I want to transform this simple table:

| Column A | Column B | Column c | Column d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 3 | 4 |
| 7 | 5 | 5 | 7 |

Into a table that looks like this with vectors of rolling correlation.

| AB | AC | AD | BC | BD | CD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I tried the rollapply function and more or less every related question in the search bar and have not been able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690809/calculate-rolling-correlation-using-rollapply#comment80046189_20691146) by @GGrothendieck, plus `combn()` to generate the new column names.

```
library(zoo)

# example data
set.seed(13)
dat <- data.frame(
  A = rnorm(20),
  B = rnorm(20),
  C = rnorm(20),
  D = rnorm(20)
)

pairnames <- names(dat) |>
  combn(2, \(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))

dat |>
  rollapply(10, \(x) cor(x)[lower.tri(cor(x))], by.column = FALSE) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(pairnames)
```

```r
              AB          AC          AD          BC          BD          CD
1   0.0003534898 -0.13612373 -0.22849979  0.45029555 -0.11457305 -0.26487479
2  -0.0580758074 -0.12874149  0.06382879  0.46018347 -0.07621848 -0.29229352
3   0.1551727794 -0.01388046  0.10599110  0.32994185 -0.19459186 -0.37626526
4  -0.0264603584 -0.02640355  0.21575705  0.29424980 -0.19790990 -0.35080532
5  -0.0067446215  0.04424283  0.48912209  0.47819290 -0.21369265 -0.11972016
6  -0.1970381395  0.06705549  0.37975883  0.57596940 -0.44240169 -0.06895075
7  -0.2725443707  0.11127621  0.42059540  0.67974874 -0.38430076 -0.09602750
8  -0.0434380298  0.12698397  0.67938827  0.58240537 -0.32976570 -0.26464101
9   0.1026328910  0.34521756  0.66884148  0.16218774 -0.09503962 -0.02151401
10  0.0717026253  0.31339628  0.75363354 -0.03758187  0.04365913  0.09453714
11  0.0861075966  0.19405089  0.83701868  0.03339110 -0.03997420  0.14340951
```

Comment: Thank you @zephryl I was able to append your solution to my problem and it worked. May I ask what the "\x" does?

Comment: `\(x)` is shorthand for an ‘anonymous function — it’s equivalent to `function(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# make some example data
d <- data.frame(A = sample(1:10), B = sample(1:10), C = sample(1:10), D = sample(1:10))

# define what kind of rolling correlation we want to do
my_rollcor <- function(x) {
  zoo::rollapply(
    x, width = 3, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA,
    FUN = \(y) cor(y[,1], y[,2])
  )
}

# apply the rolling correlation to the combination of columns
out <- combn(d, 2, FUN = my_rollcor)
out <- as.data.frame(out)
# finally, make the correct names for those columns
names(out) <- combn(names(d), 2, \(x) paste0(x[[1]], x[[2]]))


# print the output
out
```

> ```
>             AB          AC         AD          BC         BD          CD
> 1           NA          NA         NA          NA         NA          NA
> 2  -0.85148509  0.93676591  0.2726855 -0.61413236  0.2723189  0.59213691
> 3   0.19966750  0.89340515 -0.3662897  0.61858957  0.8386279  0.09078413
> 4   0.93325653  0.84855529  0.3394221  0.98198051  0.6546537  0.78571429
> 5   0.18898224  0.94491118  0.1428571  0.50000000 -0.9449112 -0.18898224
> 6  -0.59030128  0.98974332 -0.6185896 -0.69955860 -0.2690610 -0.50000000
> 7  -0.09078413  0.92857143 -0.7857143 -0.45392065 -0.5447048 -0.50000000
> 8  -0.97986371  0.14803423  0.2448990  0.05241424 -0.4335550 -0.92261291
> 9  -0.38572714 -0.09078413  0.8660254  0.95382097  0.1272570  0.41931393
> 10          NA          NA         NA          NA         NA          NA
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Axeman, I attempted to adapt this to my scenario, however, I was confused as to why the rolling correlation started from a row not equivalent to the width as this is what I was expecting. I was able to learn from this response however.